# Simple Jquery UI datepicker not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I want to set a simple Datepicker on a textfield like the one on this site
https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

So i created a new project to try it out first. I copied the code from the site into my project so it would be the same. this is what i put in the `<head>` tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

And this is what i wrote int the  `<body>` tag.

`<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>`

I thought that's all what was needed for it to work but i guess i was wrong because the datepicker doesn't show and this is all i get

http://i.gyazo.com/55f78859b6fd930f5ba9a4b6281bc0bf.png

this is a new WebApplication project so the rest of the code should be fine but just to be sure here is what's on the layout page

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
   <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#datepicker").datepicker();
            alert("test");
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new {area = ""}, new {@class = "navbar-brand"})
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
            </ul>
            @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr/>
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
    </footer>
</div>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

and this is on the index page from home

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>ASP.NET</h1>
        <p class="lead">ASP.NET is a free web framework for building great Web sites and Web applications using HTML, CSS and JavaScript.</p>
        <p><a href="http://asp.net" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker">
</p>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Getting started</h2>
            <p>
                ASP.NET MVC gives you a powerful, patterns-based way to build dynamic websites that
                enables a clean separation of concerns and gives you full control over markup
                for enjoyable, agile development.
            </p>
            <p>
                <a class="btn btn-default" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301865">Learn more &raquo;</a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Get more libraries</h2>
            <p>NuGet is a free Visual Studio extension that makes it easy to add, remove, and update libraries and tools in Visual Studio projects.</p>
            <p>
                <a class="btn btn-default" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301866">Learn more &raquo;</a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Web Hosting</h2>
            <p>You can easily find a web hosting company that offers the right mix of features and price for your applications.</p>
            <p>
                <a class="btn btn-default" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301867">Learn more &raquo;</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The code is working fine, is the files loading correctly? http://jsfiddle.net/1shjejux/

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: By default the datepicker doesn't show up until you click on the input field. Did you do that?

Comment: @Barmar yes i did click on the input file.

Comment: @redbmk no errors are shown in the console.

Comment: Is your web page on a server or in a local file? If it's a local file, you need to put `http:` prefixes on all the URLs.

Comment: But if that's the problem, you should see errors in the console saying that the scripts can't be loaded.

Comment: @Barmar i am using localhost and even when i put the `http:` prefix it's still the same. However there are no errors in the console saying that the scripts can't be loaded

Comment: By local file I meant `file:///pathname.html`, not `http://localhost/pathname.html`

Comment: If you put `alert("running");` before `$("#datepicker").datepicker()`, do you get the alert?

Comment: @Barmar yes the alert is shown

Comment: If you view the input element in the DOM inspector, do you see `class="hasDatepicker"` added to it?

Comment: No it has no class just the `type="text"` and `id="datepicker"`

Comment: He has not shown all his code.  Scope/Callback issue most likely.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask